# how do java set judge the similar ListNode

Tags: java, set, hashset

when I'm solving the problem [Intersection of Two Linked Lists](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/) from Leetcode, I found that the HashSet solution doesn't work on my computer.
The return result is always null, but it works well on Leetcode.

```
public ListNode getIntersectionNode(ListNode headA, ListNode headB) {
    Set<ListNode> hashSet = new HashSet<ListNode>();
    ListNode curNode = headA;
    while (curNode!=null){
        hashSet.add(curNode);
        curNode=curNode.next;
    }
    curNode=headB;
    while (curNode!=null){
        if (!hashSet.add(curNode)){
            return curNode;
        }
        curNode=curNode.next;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not from HashSet on your Computer but it's from the input examples, make sure that you used the same ListNode Instances for the Intersection part on the 2 LinkedList for example

```java
ListNode n = new ListNode(1);
ListNode n2 = new ListNode(2);
        
ListNode n3 = new ListNode(3);
n.next = n3;
n2.next = n3;
```

Now the next of n and n2 will be the same instance so when the HashSet try to add n3 it will return false and your code will return it,

the other solution is to override `equals` and `hashcode` the ListNode class so The HashSet will compare nodes by values and you can use different instances with the same value and your code will works